# UIScrollView is clipped and does not scroll with Autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I created a custom navigation menu in my app and I want to show some info with a scrollview.

I have a mainViewController where I have a custom navigation menu at the top, and a view (placeholder). Then I created a custom segue and 3 more views, corresponding to the 3 tabs of the custom menu. These views (viewA, viewB and viewC) are smaller to fit in the placeholder so the user will see the custombar at the top and the info corresponding to viewA (B or C) in the placeholder. This is the schema of my mainViewController.

[image]

In viewA I want to display some info in a scrollview. This is my schema:

[image]

However the viewA is clipped and it does not scroll down. But if I make my scrollview smaller it scrolls down. I guess the problem is related with the Bottom Layout Guide spacing constrain since my view goes inside of a placeholder.What I am doing wrong? I want to support both iPhone 3.5 and 4-inch screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sound like if you don´t set contentSize of your scrollview.

if your scrollview.contentSize frame is more bigger than your scrollview frame, your scrollview will not scrolling, so you need to set your scrollview.contentSize more bigger than your scrollView frame for scrolling.

Comment: I added this in viewWillAppear and it is still not scrollable     [self.mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2000)]

Comment: You are not changing the scrollview frame in the method `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` or other executed after viewWillAppear yes??

Comment: I dont change the frame. Where should I set the content size?

Comment: depends if you are implementing other methods or not. But if you are doing something in viewDidLoad for example, there isn´t any problem because -viewWillAppear is executed after. I would try to set the frame of your uiscrollview and after the contentSize, and in the method -ViewDidAppear for example check the size and contentSize, maybe they are being changed

Comment: I am not implementing any other method. I tried setting both the frame and contentsize and the result is the same. The scrollview does not scroll.

Comment: I am using autolayout, do I still need to change frame and content size?

Comment: Frame no, contentSize yes, but it´s a strange behavior

Comment: I set the contentsize to 1000,1000 and nothing. I guess it is sth related with the constraints and autolayout

Comment: I created a new project and I added to a main view a scrollview with autolayout and constraint. I set the contentSize property of this scroll to `[self.scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];` and works. Be sure you have connected your scroll in your xib and your .h file. I don´t see any problem if you use constraint for your behavior

Comment: Solved. First problem was that I didn't set the contentSize. Then I added in the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear and it was not working. After setting it in the viewDidAppear it is working. Thanks for your help.